# 9.13 lab Thesaurus Lab

Tags: python

Given a set of text files containing synonyms for different words, complete the main program to output the synonyms for a specific word. Each text file contains synonyms for the word specified in the file’s name, and each row within the file lists the word’s synonyms that begin with the same letter, separated by a space. The program reads a word and a letter from the user and opens the text file associated with the input word. The program then stores the contents of the text file into a dictionary predefined in the program. Finally the program searches the dictionary and outputs all the synonyms that begin with the input letter, one synonym per line, or a message if no synonyms that begin with the input letter are found.

Hints: Use the first letter of a synonym as the key when storing the synonym into the dictionary. Assume all letters are in lowercase.

```
synonyms = {}   # Define dictionary

file_name = input() #getting the file name without the txt
k = open(f'{file_name}.txt')#now we open the file
letter = input()#we get the letter that it will stop at
contents = k.readlines() #read the lines and its assigned as contents
word_list = [] #defining a list

for line in contents: #for each line in contents
    #word_list = lines.split()
    for word in line.split(): # and for each word in each line split it
        word_list.append(word)  #for each word in the list ad it to the list word list  
       
for word in word_list:#for each word in the word list
    if (word[0] in synonyms.keys()):#if word[0] which is the first letter is a key then execute following code
        synonyms [word[0]].append(word)#if the first letter in the word has a word then add it to synonynms
        #print(synonyms, word[0])
    else:#if the above doesn't happen the the first letter makes a new word
        synonyms [word[0]] = [word]#making a new line for this word
        print(synonyms)
       
       
# Start using the dictionary here    
print(synonyms [word])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have shown us your objective and your code, but you have forgotten to state your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.